# Javascript charting library with millisecond precision for X-axis (timeseries)?

Tags: javascript, charts, time-series

I want to use a open source javascript charting library to plot timeseries data, but my requirement is that it should support millisecond precision for the X-axis. Is there any such out there? How about precision upto seconds?

Additional requirement is that I prefer to do less work in my javascript code. So the ideal solution would be able to read a csv file to get the data and plot. Something like the temperatures.csv example of dygraph: http://dygraphs.com/index.html

An additional nice to have would be support for multiple Y-axes, but that's probably a whole another question.

Example input data would be:

```
2012-12-12 21:20:01.134000,0.0524060
2012-12-12 21:20:02.374000,0.0635470
2012-12-12 21:20:03.493000,0.0754630
2012-12-12 21:20:04.647000,0.0557800
2012-12-12 21:20:05.693000,0.1131610
2012-12-12 21:20:06.767000,0.0454080
2012-12-12 21:20:07.905000,0.0455790
2012-12-12 21:20:09.194000,0.0543930
2012-12-12 21:20:10.344000,0.0912380
2012-12-12 21:20:11.617000,0.0368600
2012-12-12 21:20:12.760000,0.0895100
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your millisecond requirement is meaningless as any decent graphing software has you determine the scale and axes. You could always just multiply by 1000 and lo and behold .001 s just became 1ms

Comment: I want to plot the date+hour+second+millisecond combination. At most, I can skip the millisecond requirement, but thats all. Multiplying by 1000 doesn't make sense in that case. Thanks.

Comment: How about converting the date-time to standard ticks (like what `Date.now()` returns)? Then you can optionally subtract some reasonable minimum date to get the number within a range the charting tool can handle.

Comment: I was hoping for something that can directly read from the data from a csv and plot it. Something like what dygraph does (but it doesn't support ms). I will add that requirement in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @allrite You are not understanding. Multiply your numbers by 1000 you lost nothing, and can get whatever granularity you want. You can also define the scale. Go between 5 and 12 looks like it will cover what you want.

Comment: @thatidiotguy , Hi, lets take a concrete example so that I understand better. Suppose, I need to plot these two data points (date, value): `2012-12-12 21:20:05.693000,0.1131610
2012-12-12 21:20:06.767000,0.0454080`. What do you suggest I multiply by 1000? Thanks again for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

AmCharts http://www.amcharts.com/ supports both milliseconds on x axis and multiple value axes. It does't have build-in cvs loader, but there is an example of how to do that:http://blog.amcharts.com/2011/03/amcharts-javascript-tutorials-part-2.html

Comment: Thanks! It looks like amcharts is not open source or free though.